# Django rest framework custom user registration

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, serialization

I am trying to get django rest framework user registration working and I am stuck. I have a custom user that adds a field to the django auth user and I am following the first answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47691718/django-creating-a-custom-user-with-the-django-rest-framework) but it's giving me a 'KeyError' and I don't really know how to solve it. Any help is appreciated!

Here is my Model:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    birthday = models.DateField()
```

Here the Serializer:

```
class CustomUserSerilizer(serializers.Serializer):
    birthday = serializers.DateField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('birthday')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    custUser = CustomUserSerilizer(required=False)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'custUser')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('custUser')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        Customer.objects.update_or_create(user=user,**profile_data)
        return user
```

And the Views:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_auth(request):
    serialized = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serialized.is_valid():
        serialized.save()
        return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serialized._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  494.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in handle_exception
  454.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  491.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py" in handler
  53.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Projects\djangoproject\app\test\views.py" in create_auth
  46.         serialized.save()

File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in save
  214.             self.instance = self.create(validated_data)

File "C:\Projects\djangoproject\app\test\serializers.py" in create
  27.         profile_data = validated_data.pop('custUser')

Exception Type: KeyError at /users/register
Exception Value: 'custUser'
```

Comment: share your traceback or error log

Comment: @SaifulAzad I forgot to do it, done!

Comment: why do u make `custUser = CustomUserSerilizer(required=False)` ? 
The model definition says that it should be the mandatory field. 
However, please apply check like this  ``custUser` in validated_data`
at create method on serialzser.

Answer (score 0):

```
custUser = CustomUserSerilizer(required=False)
```

So, user may or may not pass field `custUser` as payload. As it is `required=False` it simply pass the `is_valid()` but in `profile_data = validated_data.pop('custUser')` raise KeyError because the payload does not contains any field `custUser`. To avoid this error apply check in `def create(self, validated_data)`. Something like that

```
if custUser in validated_data:
     profile_data = validated_data.pop('custUser')
```

However, From your model definition (`CustomUser`) `birthday` should be a mandatory field. But I don't know why in Serializer you have kept that `birthday`. I hope by making `required=False` will solve your problem.

Comment: OK, I get what you say now. The thing is the field has to be compulsory. When I do required=True and I pass this json `{"username":"something","password":"pass","first_name":"Test","last_name":"Testing","email":"a@a.com","birthday":"2011-01-01"}` I get `"custUser": [
        "This field is required."
    ]` Let me modify my question

Comment: Your payload is not correct. It should be 

`{"username":"something","password":"pass","first_name":"Test","last_name":"Testing","email":"a@a.com","custUser":{"birthdate":"2011-01-01"}}`

Comment: Then I deserve an acceptance and upvote. It encourages the user more.

Comment: Can you update your answer to include the right payload?